# Receiving the undefined response and error 400

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

here is my index.js file where I am fetching response using open ai API, and its working properly.
but I am trying to use this function and passing a smart contract as argument using Fs then I am getting undefined and 400 response ..

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: {open_ai_key},

});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
async function genrateScript(smartContractCode) {
    try {
        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `Here is the smart contract code : ${smartContractCode} , write the test script for hardhat in Js`,
            max_tokens: 10000,
            temperature: 0.5,
        });
        console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}


module.exports = { genrateScript }
```

here is the another file where I am using the function :

```
const genrateScript = require("./index");
const fs = require("fs");

const contract = fs.readFileSync("./smartContract.sol", "utf-8");
console.log(typeof contract)
console.log(contract);

async function main() {
  try {
    console.log("Contract:", contract);
    const testCode = await genrateScript.genrateScript(contract);
    console.log(testCode);


    // fs.writeFileSync("./testScript.js", testCode);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("not getting the right ans");
  }
}

main();
```

also the Fs.readFileSync is working properly and reading the data from the file.

Comment: `generateScript()` doesn't return anything, what are you expecting `testCode` to be set to?

Comment: Add `return response.data.choices[0].text;` after the `console.log` call.